# Convert timestamp to UTC timezone

Tags: java, timezone

```
public static long getCurrentEpochTimeStamp(String timeStamp) throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.0Z'");
    Date date = sdf.parse(timeStamp);
    return date.getTime();
}
```

This method returns epoch current timestamp, I need to convert this to UTC timezone.

Answer (score 6):

Set time zone to your `SimpleDateFormat`  object.

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Date is always in UTC and you cannot convert it. The problem is how to parse string representation. If timeStamp contains timezone, then pattern "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.0Z'" is incorrect because it does not parse timezone. It should be "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" if timezone is in RFC 822 format, use `X` instead of `Z` if timezone is in ISO 8601. See SimpleDateFormat API