# How to I convert long (currentTimeInMillis) to UTC timestamp?

Tags: java, scala, time, utc

My client is sending me `Long` which could be thought as

```
scala> System.currentTimeMillis
res3: Long = 1441056836609

scala>
```

How do I convert that into `UTC` timeStamp?

On Server, we are using `Java 8`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert timestamp to UTC timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431402/convert-timestamp-to-utc-timezone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am doing

I am using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/) and doing

```
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime.now.toString
```

On `client` I see it as

```
Wed, 02 Sep 2015 20:57:34 GMT
```

and on `server` I see it as

```
2015-09-02T20:24:43.594Z
```

**P.S.** Don't compare values, they are copied differently, the format is what I wanted to share

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `Instant` class methods.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

Instant.ofEpochMilli(<yourmillis>).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toString();
```

Your example date would be `"2015-08-31T21:33:56.609Z"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Date dateFromTime = new Date(timeInMillis);
```

That will get a Date object, which you can then spit out in a proper UTC format using

```
DateFormat dateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat(/*UTC Format String*/, Locale./*Your Locale here*/);
System.out.printf("%s\n", dateFormatter.format(dateFromTime));
```

Comment: Given that the OP **specifically** says they are using Java 8 why are you recommending an absolutely ancient API??

Comment: You can propose your own solution if you think you have a better one.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Last I heard, the Date class (and the Calendar class) had not  been deprecated.  In my opinion, there are some problems that are solved no less elegantly with the earlier classes ... and if you're aware of their limitations then there really isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using scala, I would suggest you use the scala way, [nscala-time](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time) is a very good library

```
scala> import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._

scala> DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.UTC)

scala> new DateTime(1441056836609L)
res1: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2015-08-31T21:33:56.609Z
```