# How to convert Long local timestamp to String UTC timestamp

Tags: java, java-8, timezone, timestamp

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320428/how-to-i-convert-long-currenttimeinmillis-to-utc-timestamp?lq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) is quite close to mine, However I find the answer not suitable for me. I have timestamp as Long.

```
ts = 1362156863140L
```

As it is Long I consider it as timezone naive timestamp, is that right? It is timestapm in local time in Cologne - UTC+0200 (CET). So when I convert it to String timezone aware timestamp I want to obtain:

```
2013-03-01T14:54:23.140Z
```

or

```
2013-03-01T16:54:23.140+02:00
```

I'm using solution from answer in the beginning of my question:

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp).atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("+2"));
```

which returns:

```
2013-03-01T18:54:23.140+02:00
```

another timezone:

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp).atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("Z"));
```

returns:

```
2013-03-01T16:54:23.140Z
```

So those methods does not really change the timezone, they just change representation of timestamp. I also tried another method:

```
OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```

But results are exactly the same. [This solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609360/converting-local-timestamp-to-utc-timestamp-in-java) was useful, but original approach:

```
int offset = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam").getRawOffset();
long newTime = timestamp - offset;
```

does not concider summer/winter time. And suggested answers use Calendar class, which is obsolete for JDK8. What works and is obvious enough is:

```
OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(Timestamp), ZoneId.of("UTC")).minusSeconds(7200);
```

But it is defenetly not a proper way to do this, so how can I do that with timezone?

Comment: Your question is too broad? Tell us exactly what you need?

Comment: How to convert this 1362156863140L to that 2013-03-01T14:54:23.140Z

Comment: "As it is Long I consider it as timezone naive timestamp". I'd say the opposite. Given that a long cannot (easily) contain timezone information, it is not portable to store it this way. A long timestamp must be an instant in time irrespective of a time zone (i.e. a Unix timestamp).

Comment: This is what I am getting for your input timestamp value. `2013-03-01T21:24:23.140`

Comment: Either your assumptions are wrong or your long value is.  A long value like yours would normally denote a number of milliseconds since the epoch of Jamuary 1, 1970, 00:00 UTC. Understood this way, your long value denotes `2013-03-01T16:54:23.140Z`, not `2013-03-01T14:54:23.140Z` (`Z` means UTC). If someone gava you the long value and intended the latter, they did things in a non-standard way that is bound to cause confusion. And if so, I don’t know how they would have handled summer time, so I also cannot tell you how you should handle it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that timestamp is in `UTC` and you need to change timestamp to `CET`. Take a look at `withZoneSameInstant()` method, might be helpful.

```
    long timeStamp = 1362156863140L;
    ZoneId sourceZone = ZoneId.of("UTC");
    ZoneId targetZone = ZoneId.of("CET");
    String s = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeStamp), sourceZone)
            .withZoneSameLocal(targetZone)
            .toString();
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: I finally used that: `Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp).atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("Z")).withOffsetSameLocal(ZoneOffset.of("+2"));` but I still have no idea how to handle summer time

Comment: Don’t rely on three letter time zone abbreviations, they are not standardized and not unique. For the time in Köln/Cologne I suggest `ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")`. Your code reflects a good guess at how to interpret the asker’s long value, but we cannot be sure.

Comment: @Charlie4fun ZonedDateTime handles summer/winter time automatically as far as I know, but you should use ZoneId rather then offsets like "+2"