# Java - Convert From A Timezone Different From Local To UTC

Tags: java, timezone, utc

So from all the posts I read about this issue (for example, [Convert timestamp to UTC timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431402/convert-timestamp-to-utc-timezone)).

I learn that a way to do this conversion is :

```
SimpleDateFormat dfmaputo = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
dfmaputo.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
long unixtime = dfmaputo.parse(data.get(1)).getTime();
unixtime = unixtime / 1000;

output: 
original date (Maputo Timezone) -- 11/5/2015 1:39:45 PM
unix timestamp in UTC --- 1446687585
data.get(1) is the string with the maputo datetime.
```

I don't understand why I'm not getting the UTC value. When I convert the unix timestamp, that I was expecting to be in UTC, I get the original datetime with Maputo Timezone.

Am I missing something?

Do I need to convert first to my local timezone and than to UTC?

**EDIT: Solution**

```
Calendar maputoDateTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Maputo"));
maputoDateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Long unixtimeGMT = maputoDateTime.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
```

Instead of SimpleDateFormat I should use Calendar.

First I needed to set the input date's timezone (Africa/Maputo) and then set it to the one I needed (GMT). And only then I could get the correct unix timestamp.

Thanks to @BastiM reply in [How to change TIMEZONE for a java.util.Calendar/Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470830/how-to-change-timezone-for-a-java-util-calendar-date)

Thank you for your replies and help.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add `CAT` timezone identifier to the end of string and formatter mask has `z` letter? If thats what you always get and source data does not give timezone value.

```
    String sdt = "11/5/2015 11:39:45 PM CAT";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a z", Locale.US);
    Date dt = sdf.parse(sdt);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(dt.getTime());
    System.out.println(dt + ", utc=" + dt.getTime());
    System.out.println(cal);
```